# SQL Server DateTime Indication for today and yesterday

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have small table

```
Create Table TestDates
(
  TestDateId int identity (1,1),
  RunDateTime DateTime
)
```

I will insert some values to the table

```
Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
(getdate())

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(DAY,  -1, GETDATE()))

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(DAY,  -2, GETDATE()))

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(DAY,  -3, GETDATE()))

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(Hour,  -34, GETDATE()))

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(Hour,  -12, GETDATE()))
```

I manage to execute distinct query that brings me only time

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
DATENAME(hour, RunDateTime) + ':' + 
DATENAME(mi, RunDateTime) AS  DistinctDate
from TestDates
```

But I need to indicate times that appears today or yesterday

For example

```
DistinctDate   IsToday   IsYesterday

10:33           N          Y
20:31           Y          N
8:33            N          N
```

Please help

Comment: The day before today is called **yesterday**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use a case statement with a datediff.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
DATENAME(hour, RunDateTime) + ':' + 
DATENAME(mi, RunDateTime) AS  DistinctDate,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, RunDateTime, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END IsToday,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, RunDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END IsYesterday
from TestDates
```

Answer (score 2):

One method to determine if the date is today or yesterday is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
       DATENAME(hour, RunDateTime) + ':' + DATENAME(mi, RunDateTime) AS  DistinctDate,
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,RunDateTime) = DATEPART(day,GetDate()) THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 END as IsToday 
  FROM TestDates
```

another method is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
       DATENAME(hour, RunDateTime) + ':' + DATENAME(mi, RunDateTime) AS  DistinctDate,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,RunDateTime,getdate()) = 0 THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 END as IsToday
  FROM TestDates
```

The IsToday column would indicate today when 1 else yesterday.  This shouls work when you only need to identify between the two.

The end result based on your example is:

```
DistinctDate   IsToday

10:33           0
20:31           1
8:33            0
```

Comment: Could you post all sql query ?